# ¿Cómo recorro este array?

Tags: javascript, array

estoy aprendiendo Javascript, y el curso que estoy siguiendo cuenta con este problema, en una heladería no se cuenta con una lista de precios en el negocio para los clientes, lo que hay que hacer es un programa en el que el cliente ingrese el dinero con el que cuenta y el programa regrese el helado más caro que se completa, la forma en que el instructor lo resuelve está muy bien más sin embargo, debido a que la etapa del curso es aún muy introductoria lo hace de una manera en que puede ser mejorada a mi parecer (hace un if por cada helado, lo cual que aunque funciona, a la hora de un proyecto real me imagino que sería muy poco eficiente codificarlo de esa manera) así que me puse como reto tratar de resolverlo poniendo la lista de helados con sus precios en un array y por medio de un bucle recorrerlo y según la cantidad que haya ingresado el cliente devolver el resultado deseado, solo que no lo logro.

```
<script>
    'use strict'
    let dinero = parseFloat(prompt('¿Cuánto dinero tienes?'));

    let helados = [
        ['Helado de agua'][0.6],
        ['Helado de crema'][1],
        ['Bombón Heladix'][1.6],
        ['Bombón Heladovich'][1.7],
        ['Bombón Helardo'][1.8],
        ['Bote con Confites'][2.9],
        ['Bote 1/4L'][2.9]
    ];

    for (let i = 1; i < helados.length; i++) {
        for (let helado in helados) {
            if (dinero < helados[helado[1]]) {
                alert('No te completas para nada :(');
                break;
            } else if (dinero >= helados[helado[i]] && dinero < helados[helado[i + 1]]) {
                document.write('Lo más caro que te completas es un' + helados[helado][0]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

También me gustaría saber sugerencias para mejorar mi lógica de programación para dominar las bases del lenguaje lo más pronto posible y por ende conseguir trabajo de la misma manera, muchas gracias

Comment: No puedes, porque no es un arreglo válido, confirma agregando `console.log(helados);`, aparecen todos los elementos como no definidos.

Comment: Que quieres decir con el helado más caro que se completa? Podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: @JhonRayo99 por ejemplo, alguien ingresa que cuenta con 1 dólar (o cualquier moneda) lo más caro que se completa sería el Helado de Crema, no sé si me explico

Comment: @Triby tienes razón, lo voy a verificar, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El arreglo de helados no es válido, podes armarlo de varías maneras pero por como vi que estabas queriendo recorrerlo me imagino que querías armar un arreglo de objetos. Sería algo así (también te deje otros comentarios sobre errores que vi en el código):

```js
let dinero = parseFloat(prompt('¿Cuánto dinero tienes?'));

/** en js, [] esto es un array y esto {} es un objeto
    (aun que en js en el fondo todo es un objeto)
*/
let helados = [
    { nombre: 'Helado de agua', precio: 0.6 },
    { nombre: 'Helado de crema', precio: 1 },
    { nombre: 'Bombón Heladix', precio: 1.6 },
    { nombre: 'Bombón Heladovich', precio: 1.7 },
    { nombre: 'Bombón Helardo', precio: 1.8 },
    { nombre: 'Bote con Confites', precio: 2.9 },
    { nombre: 'Bote 1/4L', precio: 2.9 }
];

/** normalmente si querés elegir un item que cumple cierta
    condición sobre los demás vas a tener que recorrer todo
    el arreglo, entonces no esta bien usar 'break' porque no 
    sólo tenes que compararlo contra el dinero sino contra los
    otros helados que podes comprar con el mismo dinero para
    elegir efectivamente el más caro que puedas.
    Para esto vas a ir guardando el valor que cumpla la condición 
    en una variable externa y si algún otro cumple la condición 
    mejor que el que ya tenes, lo reemplazas
*/
let elegido = { nombre: null, precio: 0 };

/** fijate acá tambien que te te estabas perdiendo un resultado
    al recorrer el arreglo desde el 1, los arreglos arrancan del 
    indice 0 si no se define de otra manera
*/
for (let i = 0; i < helados.length; i += 1) {
    const helado = helados[i];

    /* primero chequeo que el dinero me alcanza */
    if (dinero > helado.precio) {
        /** después lo comparo contra el último elegido
            para ver si es más caro
        */
        if (helado.precio > elegido.precio) {
            elegido = helado; /* y si es más caro es el nuevo elegido */
        }
    }
}

/** en caso de que ninguno hubiese pasado
    la primera condición el nombre de mi
    objeto elegido sería null, caso contrario
    muestro el nombre
*/
if (elegido.nombre) {
    alert(`Lo más caro que te completas es un ${elegido.nombre}`);
} else {
    alert('No te completas para nada :(');
}
```

Seguro hay formas mejores de resolverlo, pero esta es una bastante simple. Espero que te sirva para entender un poco como resolver este tipo de problemas en el futuro.

Comment: @guachoscript muchas gracias amigo, ahora entiendo mejor los errores que tenía sos un crack